# Query that checks if all conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have an example table called conditions:

```
CREATE TABLE conditions (
  id int NOT NULL,
  age_from int,
  age_to int,
  height_from int,
  height_to int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I insert a couple of conditions:

```
INSERT INTO conditions (age_from, age_to, height_from, height_to) 
VALUES (10, 14, NULL, 200);
INSERT INTO conditions (age_from, age_to, height_from, height_to) 
VALUES (NULL, NULL, 170, 250);
```

Given these conditions 
a person with age: 11 and height: 180 would meet the criteria, but a person with age: 15 and height: 169 would not.

So my first thought is to count all the conditions that are met and compare to the total count of conditions.
The fact that some of these conditions can be `NULL` makes the query a bit complex.

Something along these lines would not work, since I'd have to check if the specific conditions are `NOT NULL` and then compare, which would make the query quite complex.

```
WHERE age_from <= 11 AND age_to >= 11 -- or using BETWEEN
```

Is there a more elegant way to write a query or restructure the `conditions` table to achieve my goal?

Comment: Which is the key field? If you are looking for an elegant way of writing a query- first add a Primary Key field in your table.

Comment: What are you comparing the conditions *to*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to check that all conditions are met is to find out if there are any conditions that are *not* met. Use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to invert the condition. You can deal with `NULL`s in a straightforward way - add `IS NULL` to each item, like this:

```
select count(*)
from conditions
where (age_from IS NOT NULL AND age < age_from)
  OR  (age_to IS NOT NULL AND age > age_to)
  OR  (height_from IS NOT NULL AND height < height_from)
  OR  (height_to IS NOT NULL AND height > height_to)
```

If the above query returns zero, all conditions have been met. Otherwise, the query returns the number of conditions that have not been satisfied.

**Note:** if you plan to use this query inside a `WHERE` clause, using `NOT EXISTS` operator would be more efficient than using the `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1):

In here first you create primary key in table and use below query like Please you check first database connection in correct or not

```
"Select * from tablename where `age_from` <= 11 and `age_to` >= 11";
```